# Laravel Datatable column searching on relationship

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel datatable package, all things work fine. I have a problem with relational column searching. Let me elaborate more:
I have two tables:
**ed_class (primary table)

ed_section(secondary table)**

[image: ed_class table]

[image: ed_section table]

Here the result of above tables with relationship between them.
[image]

Main data is coming from ed_section table and by making relationship i am getting classes names from ed_class table. As the data is coming from ed_section table so datatable column searching works fine on section name column but it's not working on class name column, so how to implement searching on class name column too.?

Here's datatable js code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 25,
         "ordering": false,
        //"columnDefs": [{
        //"targets": 7,
        //"orderable": false
        //}],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! url('sections/data') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'sr_no', name: 'sr_no' },
            { data: 'classid', name: 'classid' },
            { data: 'sectiontitle', name: 'sectiontitle' },
            { data: 'Option', name: 'Option' }
        ]
    });
});
```

And here's server side code (using laravel datatable package):

```
public function data(){

    $model = Section::all();
    $data =  Datatables::of($model);
    $data = $data->addColumn('sr_no', function(Section $section){

            })->editColumn('classid', function(Section $section){
                return $section->studentClass->classtitle;
            })->addColumn('Option', function(Section $section) {
                return '<div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                <li><a class="edit_section" data-id='.$section->sectionid.'> <i class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="'.url('/delete_sections/' . $section->sectionid).'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to remove this Section? \')" data-action="delete"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete"></i> Delete</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>';
            })->rawColumns(['Option']);

    $sections = $data->make(true);

    return $sections;

}
```

And this is model relationship:

```
class Section extends Model {

public function studentClass(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Classes','classid','classId');
  }

}
```

Comment: Look at [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6251551?tab=questions) you've asked. You've got some answers but you don't even care to come back to the site to confirm that it worked for you or accept the answer.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I have seen answers of those question but sorry to say that I have not try that because I have left my job..due to this I am unable to test your answer..but if you give answer to this question, I will definitely accept your answer..I need answer urgent..Hope you understand..

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, Can you please answer this one?

Answer (score 6):

Try Like this,

```
 $orders = Order::with('user');
    return Datatables::of($orders)
        ->addColumn('user', function ($order) {
            return $order->user->->name;
        })
```

In view :

```
  { "data": "user" , name : "user.name"},
```

Comment: But cannot be searched and not sortable :(

Answer (score 1):

I have find solution and want to share so that it can help others too:
 Here's server side code in controller (using laravel datatable package):

```
public function data(){

    $model = Section::with('studentClass');
    $data =  Datatables::of($model);
    $data = $data->addIndexColumn()
            ->editColumn('classid', function(Section $section){
                return $section->studentClass->classtitle;
            })->addColumn('Option', function(Section $section) {
                return '<div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                <li><a class="edit_section" data-id='.$section->sectionid.'> <i class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="'.url('/delete_sections/' . $section->sectionid).'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to remove this Section? \')" data-action="delete"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete"></i> Delete</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>';
            })->rawColumns(['Option']);

    $sections = $data->make(true);

    return $sections;

}
```

Here's datatable js code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 25,
         "ordering": false,
        "columnDefs": [
        { "searchable": false, "targets": [0,3] }
        ],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! url('sections/data') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'DT_Row_Index', name: 'DT_Row_Index' },
            { data: 'classid', name: 'studentClass.classtitle' },
            { data: 'sectiontitle', name: 'sectiontitle' },
            { data: 'Option', name: 'Option' }
        ],
        "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "Search Class: "
        }
    });
});
```